# How to instantiate an unmanaged C++ VST plugin from C#

Tags: c#, vst

I am looking to create a C# WPF app which hosts a VST plugin, routes MIDI events to it, and collects synthesized audio buffers for ASIO output.

While I have successfully used p/invoke for marshalling data to/from extern methods in "winmm.dll" to process MIDI successfully, this is a single, named dll.  I cannot find a general pattern for instantiating an unmanaged C++ synth plugin DLL from C#.

I understand I need to find an entrypoint to the selected DLL, which must be loaded, solely based upon its filename, and seek to discover which VST interfaces it supports.  My question comes down to how to actually do this in code.

(Please note, I am not seeking "use C++" as an answer, unless this is the ONLY answer.)

Comment: Short anwser: Use VST.NET (github)